# Difference between Data flow diagram and block diagram

Tags: block, diagram, dataflow-diagram

Can anyone explain the difference between Data Flow Diagram and Block Diagram ?
I Googled it but didn't get any satisfactory stuff that's why I turned to Stack Overflow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is all about the definition. [Data Flow Diagram (DFD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram) has a very well defined notation and semantic. In the other hand, any diagram made from blocks can be called [Block Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_diagram). You can call a DFD as Block Diagram, but not otherwise. Every time you use a block diagram, you have to specify what each block means, but when you use a square in a DFD, following the Yourdon/DeMarco notation, it means an input/output and so on.

Here it goes an expanded answer, copying from wikipedia:

- A data flow diagram (DFD) is a graphical representation of the "flow"
  of data through an information system, modeling its process aspects.
  A DFD is often used as a preliminary step to create an overview of
  the system, which can later be elaborated.[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_diagram) DFDs can also be used
  for the visualization of data processing (structured design).
- Block diagram is a diagram of a system in which the principal parts
  or functions are represented by blocks connected by lines that show
  the relationships of the blocks.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram) They are heavily used in the
  engineering world in hardware design, electronic design, software
  design, and process flow diagrams.
- *An interesting note about block diagrams*: Because block diagrams are a visual language for describing actions in a complex system, it
  is possible to formalize them into a specialized programmable logic
  controller (PLC) programming language. An example is the Function
  block diagram, one of five programming languages defined in part 3 of
  the IEC 61131 (see IEC 61131-3) standard.

If you go deeper looking for differences, you need to defined an analytical background. An analogy would be try to find differences between apples and bananas; they are fruits and taste good (at least to me), but they have different shapes and composition. You can establish the differences between fruits if you describe shape, color, vitamins. What are the features you are interested at evaluating  DFD and Block Diagrams to tell them apart?

Comment: Hey Darlinton thanks for help, Can u please give me a link to explore more about this difference ? +1.

Comment: Hi Muhammad. Well, you can access the wikipedia (links provided in the answer) and read the definitions for both (you will see they are different). Can you tell me what kind of difference you are looking for?

Comment: Well, Can you illustrate with real time example ?